# Send innerHTML text in URL in JSP

Tags: jsp, url, onclick, send, innerhtml

How to send innerhtml text of a tag in url on onclick event handler in JSP page and get this value in another JSP page? Here is my code

> `<a href="DocumentViewer.jsp">Hello</a>`

I want to send Hello with URL. Help?

Comment: You should write onclick event handler.

Comment: how to send value on onclick handler?

Comment: You can do it in different ways, the most simple is to use parameter in the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the value in URL on onclick event and get it using

```
request.getParameter()
```

in JSP page. Below is the example code

```
<a href="DocumentViewer.jsp?proces=something">Hello</a>
```

and get it in JSP like this.

```
String pro=request.getParameter("proces");
```

Comment: Thanks Lovish. It's working fine. but i want to take this value to next page also. How can i achieve it?